# How to get decimal limits before and after dot from DB?

Tags: java, db2

I am creating random records to be inserted in DB based on limits which I get from a table.
I collect to List each column max limit using ResultSet.getMetaData().getPrecision(i)

And have a method where I provide column types and column max values to create random values.

Problem that I met when I need to create value for Decimal I can't get how many digits should be before and after dot as getPrecision() returns the hole limit.

e.g.

```
 column1 = DECIMAL(4,2)
     getPrecision(column1) = 6
```

And my method will create = '123456'
but I need '1234.56' and the most important part that number of digits after dot should be taken from DB column parameter

```
     public List<List<String>> createRecords(List<String> columnTypes, List<Integer> columnMAxLimit) {
                List<String> record = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < columnTypes.size(); j++) {
                    switch (columnTypes.get(j)) {
                            case "DECIMAL":
 record.add(String.valueOf(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1,convertMaxValueForRandomizer(columnMAxLimit.get(j)))));
                                break;
                                case "INTEGER":
                                record.add(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()));
                                break;
                            case "CHAR":
                                record.add("'" + common.randomString(columnMAxLimit.get(j)) + "'");
                                break;
                            default:
                                log.error("Not known data type:" + columnTypes.get(j));
                        }
                    }
    return new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(record));
            }

 public int convertMaxValueForRandomizer(int maxChars) {
        String str1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < maxChars && i < 9; i++) {
            if(i>9) {
                break;
            }
         str1 = str1 + "1";
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(str1);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried [`getScale()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getScale-int-)?

Comment: For `DECIMAL` / `NUMERIC` types the metadata `getColumns()` method gets you the `#7.COLUMN_SIZE` and `#9.DECIMAL_DIGITS`. With that you should have everything you need. For other numeric types this is trickier.

Comment: @mustaccio Thnx , I tried it , but did a mistake. Now with getScale() I managed to solve my problem.

Comment: Thnx @TheImpaler